# JOIN query returning 100450(inetuser)

Tags: php, group-by, max, join

I'm making a private message system. My form posts correctly to my tables but the return query pulls something weird. I'm a bit new to joining tables...

PHP code with sql query:

```
function fetch_messages()  {
    $sql = "SELECT
                `conversations`.`con_id`,
                `conversations`.`con_subject`,
                MAX(`conversations_messages`.`message_date`) AS `con_last_reply`
            FROM `conversations`
            LEFT JOIN `conversations_messages` ON `conversations`.`con_id` = `conversations_messages`.`con_id`
            INNER JOIN `conversations_members` ON `conversations`.`con_id` = `conversations_members`.`con_id`
            WHERE `conversations_members`.`user_id` = 31
            AND `conversations_members`.`con_deleted` = 0
            GROUP BY `conversations`.`con_id`
            ORDER BY `con_last_reply` DESC";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    $conversations = array();

    while (($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))  !== false)  {

        $conversations[] = array(
        `id`        => $row['con_id'],
        `subject` => $row['con_subject'],
        `con_last_reply` => $row['last_reply']
        );
    }
    return $conversations;
}
```

Returns array:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( 
                [uid=8927072(user007) gid=100450(inetuser) groups=100450(inetuser) ] => 1
                [] => ) )
```

(It's almost like it's returning my ftp info? user007 is my ftp connection name that I have open, but that's not what is in the tables!!)

Comment: Your array output doesn't match your code at all. Are you sure you are dumping the correct array? Also mysql_ functions are deprecated and replaced with mysqli_ (or you could use PDO)

Comment: I agree, there's no way that array could have been created by your code. It doesn't have keys `id`, `subject`, and `con_last_reply`. Instead, it has something that looks like the output of the Unix `id` command as the key.

Comment: @datasage Yes I'm dumping "print_r(fetch_messages());" Yes I know that's why it's weird... yes I know mysql_functions are defunct I haven't switched over yet.

Comment: @barmar I know the keys are wrong... I wonder if I'm using a keyword as a variable name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the wrong kinds of quotes. It should be:

```
    $conversations[] = array(
    'id'        => $row['con_id'],
    'subject' => $row['con_subject'],
    'con_last_reply' => $row['last_reply']
    );
```

Backticks are like in the shell or Perl, they run the command and return its output as a string.

I had no idea until this question that PHP had this feature.

[Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php)

Comment: We have a WINNER Thanks so much : ) the ` and ' are so confusing to see.